# Symfony 4 how to render properties referenced to another entity by a @OneToOne or similar relation

Tags: doctrine, symfony4

I'm studying symfony framework for personal purposes and I'm facing an issue, which is very likely due to a lack of knowledge by my side, that is driving me crazy:
I've already successfully implemented forms which refers to a single entity (i.e. StudentEntity:class).

What i'm facing now, and can't figure out how to proceed, is that now I've an entity which is in relation to another one by a OneToOne unidirectional (i.e. StudentEntity::class has a field, anagraphic, which is mapped to StudentAnagraphicEntity:class).

What I want to achieve is to build a form which expose all the fields (either the ones from StudentEntity that the ones from StudentAnagraphicEntity) but I cannot place all the pieces togheter correctly. Anyone so gentle to explain me how to do it?

Many thanks

PS
As you can see i'm not a native english speaker so please be tollerant on my (eventually) mistakes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is explained in [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) with an example. You need to write a form type for each entity, where the parent embeds the collection of children.

Comment: For a one-to-one relation you can embed the "ChildEntityType" into "ParentEntityType" just like any other type [see here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10230)